# How to calculate the complexity of this python program? Is there any way on how this could be improved?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

Hi I'm writing this program that organizes files into a dictionary based on their extention (.exe, .py, .docx), and the method that I'm using right now uses a nested loop for doing this exact thing. The thing is that I need to loop into the list of all the extentions found by the program and check into the list of all the files where those files with the same extention are, putting then the files that correspond into the dictionary under the right key.
My current method works but I'd like to know if there are any ways to improve the time complexity of the program.

here is all the code:

```
from os import path, listdir, mkdir
import shutil


def main():
    files = listdir()
    extentions = []
    grouped = {}

    # Filter out folders from the files
    for file in files:
        if path.isdir(file):
            files.pop(files.index(file))
            continue
    
    # Get the extentions of the files for creating the folders
    for file in files:
        extention = file.split(".")[-1]
        if extention not in extentions:
            extentions.append(extention)

    # Organize files based on their extentions
    for extention in extentions:
        grouped[extention] = []
        for file in files:                     # This is the important part
            if file.endswith(extention):
                grouped[extention].append(file)
    
    print(files)
    print(extentions)
    print(grouped)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: FWIW, you don't want to `.pop` from a list while iterating over it. Also, why the 3 loops? you can do everything with a single loop and a single data-structure (you have 3)

Answer (score 2):

Complexity O(n), n - number of files in the current directory.

```py
from os import path, listdir
from collections import defaultdict


def main():
    files = listdir()
    grouped = defaultdict(list)

    for file in files:
        if path.isfile(file):
            extention = file.split(".")[-1]
            grouped[extention].append(file)

    print(files)
    print(grouped)
    print(grouped.keys())  # if you need extensions


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Nice use of *defaultdict* here. +1